# How many times will be this statement will be executed?

Tags: time-complexity

How many times will be this statement will be executed?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    p = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < n; i = i * 2)
    {
       p++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The answer should be **log(n)**, but I am getting **log(n) + 1**.

Comment: In terms of big oh *O(log(n))* is the same as *O(log(n)+1)*, and even *O(a log(n))*.

Comment: Suppose we have to find the exact value of p than how we will do it?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what will be the time complexity log(n) or ceiling of log(n)?

Comment: It does not matter, since the two are the same.

Comment: But isn't the graph of log and ceiling log different?

Comment: it does not matter: `ceil(x)` is always between `x` and `x+1`. *O(...)* does not sees this `+1` as a "difference", it would only be a problem if it was *(ceil(log(n))*n)* for example. When *n* goes to infinity, then the relative difference between *log n* and *ceil(log n)* is infinitismal small.

Comment: Do you want to say the infinitismal difference when multipiled by large value of n result in large difference in value so when frequency count is (ceil(log(n)) *n, it is better to write time complexity as (ceil(log(n)) *n rather than (log(n)) *n

Answer (score 0):

In case of time complexity, to be exact:

- 1 from `p=0;`
- [image: dgf] from the for loop
- [image: sgf] from the inside of the loop

in total it would be:

[image: dfh]

---

In case of the value of `p`:

[image: fhg]

to prove this we can say `p` is initially `0` and it is increased as long as `i` is less than `n`.

If we assume [image: gfh] , we have `k1` and `k2` before the loop ends:

[image: jty]

so `p` is increased by `1` for `k1` times. Therefore: `p=k1` at the end. We know:

- [image: jytj]
- [image: ujyut]
- [image: hrth]

Therefore:
[image: jytj]

Comment: Thanks, btw can you also provide proof?

Comment: @HritikKumar If it is a homework question, please think about the answer carefully to see if there are mistakes in it. If you find it helpful, please accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't i will be 2^k-1 ?